# The JAR file not open(it open with the winRAR)?

Tags: java

I'm working with the netbeans and I create a jar file, but it not opened with the java. When I try to open it opened with the winRAR program.
This is the MainClass code:

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String arg[]){
    Ludec cal=new Ludec();
           cal.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
           cal.setSize( 314, 380 ); 
           cal.setLocation(600,150);
           cal.setVisible( true ); 
    }

}
```

It run in the cmd by this command:
java -jar "C:\Users\Tofiq\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication1\dist\JavaApplication1.jar"
but not run by clicking and its error:
[image]

Comment: How are you generating the JAR file? What error do you get when trying to run it?

Comment: Information you give is not enough to suggest something. You need to provide more info about the problem

Comment: I creating by netbeans(clean and build main project option).It don't run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > java -jar "C:\Users\Tofiq\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication1\dist\JavaApplication1.jar" but not run by clicking and its error:

For -jar to work you need the MANIFEST file.

Answer (score 4):

Jar is an archive(Java ARchive). When you install winRar it asks you for file extension association (by default it includes .jar files as well). You can later change this association in many ways, for example :
Right click on any .jar file, 'Open With'-> 'Choose default program'->choose a program you want to use to open .jar file(don't forget to check 'Always use this program to open this kind of file').

Answer (score 3):

Just run this batch code:

```
assoc .jar=jarfile
ftype jarfile=jarfile="<insert JRE bin directory>javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*
```

This will associate `.jar` files with the `javaw` executable which is used to run .jar files

Answer (score 1):

probably because you installed winrar after installing netbeans and java, so that the .jar extension has been re-associated with winrar.

you'll need to modify the file extension .jar to be associated with the JVM